# Padding HStack in the top of any screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to put an HStack which contains two Texts in the top of any device screen.

the problem is when I use padding that I have to decide fixed size of padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                Text("Hello world!")
                Text("Hello world!")
            }.padding(.top, 100)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```